Bot/Message Extension App created using Teams Toolkit in private/shared channels
I have created a Teams Bot/Message Extension App using Teams Toolkit using VS Code. It is working properly in standard channels. I want to install it in shared/private channel.
I have added below into the manifest file. Still not able to install in the shared/private channel
"supportedChannelTypes": [
  "sharedChannels",
  "privateChannels"
]


This issue is being tracked here https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/issues/1287. Please follow the github thread for updates. Thank you.
